# Can I estimate the leakage inductance of a power transformer taken from a catalogue?

Tags: transformer, inductance

I'm using PLECS to simulate an HVDC system and I've been using two ideal transformers (Y/Y & Y/D) in order to get a 12-pulse rectification. However, now I want to consider real parameters. PLECS gives me this box to replace leakage inductance and winding resistance, as other specs, for every winding:

[image]

That being said, I've been searching for these parameters and some [catalogues](http://www02.abb.com/global/seitp/seitp202.nsf/0/be0fae657152c39dc125803d0012dd70/$file/HVDC+converter+transformers.pdf) only include its impedance in %.

[image]

With this I can know the impedance in ohms but not 'separated' as R+wL. Do you have a different approach for this? Is there a typical proportional relation between R and L depending on voltage level or MVAs? Finally, is important to mention that I only want these values to have something 'real' but not too real as I will be studying the efficiency of a converter at the DC side (after 12-pulse rectification). In other words, as minimum I have to consider overlap angle due to leakage inductance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to find "typical" L/R or X/R ratios for power transformers if you search. Also, some catalogs may state L/R. In power transformer specs, I believe it is more common to state per unit impedance and L/R ratio. When L/R ration is stated, I believe that is actually X/R at the rated frequency.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And in case L/R or X/R ratio is not shown, can I assume something to *estimate* the leakage inductance? I ask this because I've been told from Schneider  that I can calculate this inductance as Ze / (2 x Pi x Freqn). If they said that is because from above X MVA transformers, winding resistance is insignificant compared to X?

Comment: You can probably assume X/R = 5.